# What to embed the dynamic help command

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I coded a dynamic help command using the discord documentation. But to make it eye-catching, I want to embed it and display it into the users DM. 
Here is a small snippet -

```
execute(client, message, args) {
        const data = [];
        const { commands } = message.client;

        if (!args.length) {
            data.push('Here\'s a list of all my commands:'); //push on data var to append the info you want 
            data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join('\n'));
            data.push(`\nYou can send \`${prefix}help [command name]\` to get info on a specific command!`);

            return message.author.send(data, { split: true })
                .then(() => {
                    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
                    message.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands!');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
                    message.reply('it seems like I can\'t DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?');
                });
        }
```

Is there anyway I can use data.push in an embed?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean make an embed and display it with all the command names?

> Is there anyway I can use data.push in an embed

Not sure what you exactly mean but from what I understand, no, an embed has properties like fields, files, title and etc, you can set those though instead of using your current method of an array of data.

This might be what you want:

```js
execute(client, message, args) {
  const data = [];
  const { commands } = message.client;
  if (!args.length) {
    //you'll need refrence to this somehow, like const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js")    
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Here's a list of all my commands:");
      .setDescription(commands.map(cmd => cmd.name).join("\n"));
      .setFooter(`You can send \`${prefix}help [command name]\` to get info on a specific command!`);

    return message.author.send(data, { split: true })
      .then(() => {
        if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
        message.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
        message.reply('it seems like I can\'t DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?');
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, but I’ve fixed it.

```
if (!args.length) {
const title = 'Here\'s a list of all my commands:';
const description = data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join(', '));
const footer = `You can send ${prefix}help [command name] to get info on a specific command!`;
    const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setTitle(title)
    .setDescription(data)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(footer);
return message.author.send(helpEmbed)
   .then(() => {
       if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
       message.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands!');
   });
```

Try this. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Command List :")
    .setColor("GREEN")
    .setDescription(data.join(" "));
```

If you think your data will be longer than 1024 characters, try doing this :

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Command List :")
    .setColor("GREEN");
var tempDesc = "";

for (let line of data) {
    if ((tempDesc + line).length < 1024) tempDesc += line
    else {
        message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(tempDesc));
        tempDesc = "";
    }
}

if (tempDesc.length > 0) message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(tempDesc));
```